# proper Use of Indirect Reference

Tags: php

I have this indirect Reference i wonder what's the usage of this

```
$name = "Air nike";
$$name = "Registered item";
print $AirNike;
```

I was thinking to put save all the items that are registered in a document by date and I was thinking of this technique and wanted to make sure it was ok. What would be a good place to implement a technique as the indirect Reference a

Comment: Indirect references are, IMO, one of the worst features of PHP. Use an array if you need that kind of things.

Answer (score 2):

Your example code is nonsense, it tries to print a variable which is nothing like the one that I think you intended.  If you wanted to print it, you would either need to print `${'Air nike'}` or just reuse what you already have: `$$name`

As the comments to the question have mentioned, from your description this does not seem like something you should really be using in your script.

As for a good time to use these 'variable variables', arguably never. It is probably best to ignore them until such a time, if it ever comes, where you see a clear and pragmatic *need* (not *use*) for them.